# PHP : how to calculate the date based on the timezone coming from API response say SOAP request

Tags: php, date, datetime, soap

```
$date_frm_soap = '2015-12-16T22:14:04-0700';
date_default_timezone_set("PS8PDT");
```

from this how can i calculate the date based on the timezone set.
I tried the below as it is calculating time based on the time zone but 
`strtotime($date_frm_soap)` how we can convert this to UTC date format.

Links which helped me:

[convert soap time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264769/convert-soap-time-in-php)

[Convert Date in PHP to XMLGregorianCalendar format and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434135/convert-date-in-php-to-xmlgregoriancalendar-format-and-back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DateTime object, it is incredibly flexible and will recognise almost any data format you throw at it. You then set a timezone into the DateTime object and then print a formatted date in whatever format you want to see it in.

```
<?php
$date_frm_soap = '2015-12-16T22:14:04-0700';

// load the DatTime object with your date
$date = new DateTime($date_frm_soap );

// tell DateTime we want to use UTC
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo  'in date =  '. $date_frm_soap . PHP_EOL;

// output the data in which ever format you want to see it in
echo  'UTC date = '. $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This produces these results

```
in date =  2015-12-16T22:14:04-0700
UTC date = 2015-12-17 05:14:04
```

Comment: thanks riggs. if my timestamp comes something like below .how can i mange that .Lets say "2015-12-16 07:00:00 Etc/GMT"

Comment: Try it, that date format will also be recognised by DateTime just like the date in your question.